# Why a defined pointcut with @target doesn't work?

Tags: spring, annotations, spring-annotations, aspects

I'm trying to use Spring aspects to do save aditional data while storing documents with `MongoRepository`. The target is this interface:

```
@InSearch
public interface ItemRepository extends MongoRepository<Item, Long>, 
    ItemRepositoryCustom 
{
    List<Item> findAllByUsername( String username );
    List<Item> findAllBySessionId( Long sessionId );
}
```

When I use this pointcut:

```
@Pointcut( "execution(* save(..)) && " + 
    "target(org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository)" )
private void saveEntity()
{}
```

This method runs ok before `open` method is called:

```
@Before( "saveEntity() && args(entity)" )
public void beforeSavingEntity( JoinPoint jp, AuditedBean entity )
{ ... }
```

But I want it to run only with interfaces annotated with `@InSearch` so I tried to define the pointcut that way:

```
@Pointcut( "execution(* save(..)) && " +
    "target(org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository) && " +
    "@target(xx.annotations.InSearch)" )
private void saveEntity()
{}
```

The annotation definition:

```
@Target( { ElementType.TYPE} )
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface InSearch
{}
```

With this pointcut the method `beforeSavingEntity` is not called. I've not any error on log. I'm not sure if I had understood the documentation about `@target` and his differences with `@within`. I've tried also with `@within` and didn't work either.

How must I define this pointcut to select `save` methods execution in a class that implements an interface that extends `MongoRepository` and is annotated with `@InSearch`?

Thank you!

Comment: are you sure about private access modifiers? I don't remember exactly however :) Also is your `@InSearch` retained in runtime?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. The first one works as it.

Comment: Yes, I`ll add the `@InSearh` definition

Comment: The implementation class is dinamicaly created by "Spring Document - MongoDB" based in the interface definition. I think I'll have to create a new interface to use `target` instead of `@target`.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are using class-based proxies in in your application.

As annotations are not being inherited by the implementing classes in Java, try putting `@InSearch` on the implementation class.

See [Where should I put @Transactional annotation: at an interface definition or at an implementing class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120143/where-should-i-put-transactional-annotation-at-an-interface-definition-or-at-a)

Comment: As I said, the implementation class is dinamicaly created by "Spring Document - MongoDB" based in the interface definition. Annotate the class is not an option.