# Errors creating my first spring mvc project

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm new in spring mvc, I'm following a book called spring-mvc-beginners-guide. But there is some mistake in the project and I can not continue.

[This is a photo of the project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPGH4.jpg)

**DispatcherServletInitializer.java**

```
package com.packt.webstore.config;
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.packt.webstore")
public class WebApplicationContextConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling (DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new
        InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

**RootApplicationContextConfig.java**

```
package com.packt.webstore.config;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.packt.webstore.controller")
public class RootApplicationContextConfig {
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
        EmbeddedDatabase db = builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL).addScript("db/sql/create-table.sql")
                .addScript("db/sql/insert-data.sql").build();
        return db;
    }

    @Bean
    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
        return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource());
    }
}
```

**WebApplicationContextConfig.java**

```
package com.packt.webstore.config;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.packt.webstore")
public class WebApplicationContextConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling (DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new
        InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

**HomeController.java**

```
package com.packt.webstore.controller;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String welcome(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", "Welcome to Web Store!");
        model.addAttribute("tagline", "The one and only amazing web store");
        return "welcome";
    }
}
```

**ProductController.java**

```
package com.packt.webstore.controller;


@Controller
public class ProductController {

    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    @RequestMapping("/products")
    public String list(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("products", productRepository.getAllProducts());
        return "products";
    }
}
```

**Product.java**

```
package com.packt.webstore.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
public class Product implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3678107792576131001L;
    private String productId;
    private String name;
    private BigDecimal unitPrice;
    private String description;
    private String manufacturer;
    private String category;
    private long unitsInStock;
    private long unitsInOrder;
    private boolean discontinued;
    private String condition;

    public Product() {
        super();
    }
    public Product(String productId, String name, BigDecimal unitPrice) {
        this.productId = productId;
        this.name = name;
        this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
    }

    // Here i deleted getters and setter for compact code
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Product other = (Product) obj;
    if (productId == null) {
        if (other.productId != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!productId.equals(other.productId))
        return false;
    return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((productId == null) ? 0 : productId.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
}
```

**ProductRepository.java**

```
package com.packt.webstore.domain.repository;

@ComponentScan
public interface ProductRepository {
    List<Product> getAllProducts();
}
```

**InMemoryProductRepository.java**

```
package com.packt.webstore.domain.repository.impl;

@Repository
public class InMemoryProductRepository implements ProductRepository {
    @Autowired
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Override
    public List<Product> getAllProducts() {
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        List<Product> result = jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT * FROM products", params, new ProductMapper());
        return result;
    }

    private static final class ProductMapper implements RowMapper<Product> {
        public Product mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            Product product = new Product();
            product.setProductId(rs.getString("ID"));
            product.setName(rs.getString("NAME"));
            product.setDescription(rs.getString("DESCRIPTION"));
            product.setUnitPrice(rs.getBigDecimal("UNIT_PRICE"));
            product.setManufacturer(rs.getString("MANUFACTURER"));
            product.setCategory(rs.getString("CATEGORY"));
            product.setCondition(rs.getString("CONDITION"));
            product.setUnitsInStock(rs.getLong("UNITS_IN_STOCK"));
            product.setUnitsInOrder(rs.getLong("UNITS_IN_ORDER"));
            product.setDiscontinued(rs.getBoolean("DISCONTINUED"));
            return product;
        }
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.6</version>
<configuration>
<failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
</configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.packt</groupId>
  <artifactId>webstore</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

**And stacktrace**

```
GRAVE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'productController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'productRepository': No qualifying bean of type [com.packt.webstore.domain.repository.ProductRepository] found for dependency [com.packt.webstore.domain.repository.ProductRepository]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.packt.webstore.domain.repository.ProductRepository] found for dependency [com.packt.webstore.domain.repository.ProductRepository]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:350)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4743)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.packt.webstore.domain.repository.ProductRepository] found for dependency [com.packt.webstore.domain.repository.ProductRepository]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1398)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1051)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:570)
    ... 24 more

ago 11, 2017 8:32:51 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
GRAVE: Excepción enviando evento inicializado de contexto a instancia de escuchador de clase [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'productController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'productRepository': No qualifying bean of type [com.packt.webstore.domain.repository.ProductRepository] found for dependency [com.packt.webstore.domain.repository.ProductRepository]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.packt.webstore.domain.repository.ProductRepository] found for dependency [com.packt.webstore.domain.repository.ProductRepository]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:350)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4743)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.packt.webstore.domain.repository.ProductRepository] found for dependency [com.packt.webstore.domain.repository.ProductRepository]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1398)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1051)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:570)
    ... 24 more

ago 11, 2017 8:32:51 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
GRAVE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
ago 11, 2017 8:32:51 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
GRAVE: Falló en arranque del Contexto [/webstore] debido a errores previos
ago 11, 2017 8:32:51 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMACIÓN: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
ago 11, 2017 8:32:51 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMACIÓN: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
ago 11, 2017 8:32:51 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMACIÓN: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
ago 11, 2017 8:32:51 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFORMACIÓN: Server startup in 2681 ms
```

PD: I have deleted import for a compact code. If you need them, or anything else, please tell me. Thanks in advance

Comment: remove `@ComponentScan` from it is not needed there`public interface ProductRepository `

Comment: Thank you, already removed but the error remains the same

Comment: Do you Import the correct  `ProductRepository`  in your Controller?

Comment: I think so, I think but I'm not sure. I have the import in ProductController but not in the HomeController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend to choose a 'right way' in learning Spring Boot.
With 'old books' you can get the wrong experience and, as a result, spend too much time.
Spring has own very useful **[guides](https://spring.io/guides)** which can help you to start very quickly. For example:

[Serving Web Content with Spring MVC](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/)

[Handling Form Submission](https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/)

[Accessing Data with JPA](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/)

Also you can check my simple [example](https://github.com/Cepr0/crud-sb-demo) of CRUD application with Spring MVC and Spring Data JPA.

Comment: Thank you Cepr0, I'm going to try those guides

Comment: @V.Vallejo Don't forget to accept/upvote answers if they helped you... )

Answer (score 1):

Change the `@ComponentScan("com.packt.webstore.controller")` to include package where your InMemoryProductRepository is located.

Your scan cannot find the repository because it scans controllers package only.

Comment: I think it is not correct, because if I make the change you tell me there are still more errors in the stacktrace. Here you can see the current stacktrace http://textuploader.com/doyl3

Comment: it means you need HSQL DB driver dependency. In general you anyway need to fix all the errors.

Comment: But i have HSQL dependency in pom.xml and I have added hsqldb-2.3.2.jar in maven's dependencies. So what should I do to fix it?

Comment: I don't know what exactly is wrong. The posted code looks fine. Check the war file whether the jar is properly added. Could be you need another question with more details. I pointed how to fix original problem, not all possible errors in your code:-)

Answer (score 1):

replace @ComponentScan with @Component from public interface ProductRepository

Comment: I have tried it but I get the same error as in the question. Could you tell me the reason for this change? To put it like this or with ComponentScan

Comment: "@ComponentScan" used for define the package where your components located. and "@Component" used for make that class as a component.

Comment: have you tried  this package path "@ComponentScan("com.packt.webstore") 
in public class RootApplicationContextConfig {} ?

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
@Component
public interface ProductRepository {
    List<Product> getAllProducts();
}
```

`@ComponentScan` is different thing, it scan the specified package and create bean if any annotation found.

Also please refer 1 good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351780/where-should-service-annotation-be-kept-interface-or-implementation#33530450).

Comment: Thank you bro, this kind of explanation comes in handy, because I'm still starting with spring

Comment: Hello @V.Vallejo, if you're satisfied with any answer then please accept.