# How to autowire Spring services that inherit?

Tags: java, spring, inheritance

I have 2 services, EFT and Cheque that are substantially similar.

Runs fine if I mark the implementation as @service.

Otherwise I get a no such bean definition exception. No qualifying bean of type 'EftPaymentService'.

Top level interface.

```
public interface PaymentService {
  public void paymentsResponse();
}
```

Eft service interface.

```
@Service
public interface EftPaymentService extends 
  PaymentService {
   public void processEft(String code) throws PaymentsException;
}
```

Cheque service interface

```
@Service
public interface ChequePaymentService extends 
  PaymentService {
   public void processCheque(String code) throws PaymentsException;
}
```

Top level implementation

```
public abstract class PaymentServiceImpl implements PaymentService {
  @Autowired
  protected SessionFactory sftpSessionFactory;

  @Autowired
  protected SftpConfig.UploadGateway gateway;

  public void paymentsResponse(){
  } 
}
```

Eft implementation

```
public class EftServiceImpl extends PaymentsServiceImpl implements EftPaymentService {
}
```

Cheque implementation

```
public class ChequeServiceImpl extends PaymentsServiceImpl implements ChequePaymentService {
}
```

What is going on here?
Refactor using composition?

Comment: Did you check in the logs to see if the implementation class was scanned?

Comment: Marking the implementation as `@Service` is what you should do, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Is it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351780/where-should-service-annotation-be-kept-interface-or-implementation

Comment: Yes, it is. You found the question now all that's left is read the answers and understand them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Annotate implementations with `@Service` & use constructor-based injection.

Comment: This works. Have been annotating the services on the basis that referencing the interface is more generic. It doesn't work in this case, although I still don't quite know why.

Comment: `@Service` is just a specialization of `@Component`; they behave exactly the same. By its name, the former communicates some additional intent. I believe the intent of `@Component` (thus `@Service`) it to annotate Spring "bean" implementations, which are typically concrete classes, not interfaces. I guess I'm saying I wouldn't expect putting it on an interface to ever work. Good luck.