# Should @EventListener methods be included on the interface?

Tags: java, spring, events, coding-style

Maybe this is a question prone to be deleted, but just in case.

I've had a doubt lately while doing `@EventListener` annotated methods on my services if those methods should be included on the service's interface or not.

I mean, with a class like:

```
class FooServiceImpl implements FooService {
    @EventListener
    public void doSomethingWithEvent(ApplicationEvent event){
        // do something
    }
}
```

Should `doSomethingWithEvent` be included in `FooService`?

I think it shouldn't as the method is not meant to be directly invoked by any other instance but the one managing the events.

But, on the other hand, I would have a public method on my service that is not included on the interface, and for some reason, that smells bad to me (maybe it's just a habit).

So, what to do? Is there any convention regarding this?

Comment: It depends on whether you consider this service as required to react to these types of events or not.

Comment: I'd do an own interface for `doSomethingWithEvent` and call it - like - `ApplicationEventAware`. All in all I think this is off topic as primarily opinion based.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where should @Service annotation be kept? Interface or Implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351780/where-should-service-annotation-be-kept-interface-or-implementation)

Comment: @pvpkiran, not really a duplicate. `@Service` annotation means a different thing to `@EventListener` one.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov In what way it is different, Spring handles it the same way. May be intrernals are different. But the answer to that questions holds good even for this

Comment: @Clijsters, there is one point to having it in interface: "I want all conforming implementations of this service to react to this event in some way". Which is not a really compelling one, and can be solved in different ways, but still.

Comment: @pvpkiran, it's not about how Spring handles something, it's about meaning you attach to a piece of text as a programmer.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Then this method is a strict part of your service (contract) and would fit to the interface. But I don't think this is good practice. I'd definitive go with the `*-Aware` approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say this is **primarily opinion based**, because afaik there is no *real* convention for this question. I didn't flag your question, because I think it is a good one and because I'm not sure if it is on or off topic.

---

Just ask yourself the following question: Is `doSomethingWithEvent()` part of my service? Is it part of the contract, its consumers (classes which use `FooService`) are using?

Or to break it down: *Is there any case where a method, which uses `FooService` should be able to call `doSomethingWithEvent()` directly?*
I don't think so.

So, with this in mind, basically: **No, you shouldn't include that method in your interface.** Programming against interfaces means you provide interfaces to your consumers and they can talk to them wihtout needing to know its implementations. That means also there could be (imho [*should be*](https://www.symphonious.net/2011/06/18/the-single-implementation-fallacy/)) different implementations for one interface. Some might provide an EventListener, some won't provide one.

I personally would prefer to create an own interface - let's say `ApplicationEventAware` and implement this in `FooServiceImpl`. You will find this approach in Spring many times. For this case I would name my implementation `EventAwareFooService`, and avoid `*Impl` classes, because [this is bad design](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/InterfaceImplementationPair.html) in my personal opinion. ([and some might call it an anti pattern](https://marekdec.wordpress.com/2011/12/06/explicit-interface-per-class-antipattern/))

---

There is already [`ApplicationListener<E extends ApplicationEvent>`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationListener.html) So why not just implementing that?

Comment: I'm not using that, as it's the "old" way of doing event listening https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/11/better-application-events-in-spring-framework-4-2

Comment: Nothing there says _"old" way_, does it? Yeah new annotations are awesome but wouldn't a dedicated interface the best approach for your specific case?

Comment: @Alfergon I added some references and tried to make my statement more clear

Comment: Hi Clijsters, if you find that a question is **primarily opinion-based**, please flag it as such (or vote it as such when you are over 3,000 reputation), instead of answering it. POB questions are off-topic at Stack Overflow.

Comment: If I where sure on that, I had flagged it. Im not sure whether this question is more on a best practice request or an opinion based question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that there is a convention regarding this. However, I agree that `doSomethingWithEvent()` shouldn't be included in `FooService`. It will be interesting to see other peoples opinions on this.