# Consider defining a bean of type in your configuration with my Service

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, spring-data

I have this situation with my code even after I added the @Component, @Service and @Repository annotation to my classes:

this is the resource for it:

```
package app.gym.v1.Resource.API;

import app.gym.v1.Model.Domain.Gym;
import app.gym.v1.Service.GymService;
import app.gym.v1.Utility.Constant.SwaggerConstant;
import io.swagger.annotations.Api;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.responses.ApiResponse;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.responses.ApiResponses;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.OK;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/gym")
@Api(tags = {SwaggerConstant.API_TAG3})
public class GymControl {
    private GymService gymService;

    @Autowired
    public GymControl(GymService gymService) {
        this.gymService = gymService;
    }

    @ApiOperation(value = "Get all available gyms", notes = "Retrieve a list of all gyms")
    @ApiResponses({@ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "The list of gyms retrieved"),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "The request is malformed or invalid"),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "404", description = "The resource URL was not found on the server"),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "An internal server error occurred"),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "403", description = "You are not authorized. Please authenticate and try again"),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "401", description = "You don't have permission to this resource")
    })
    @GetMapping("/list_gym")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Gym>> getAllGyms() {
        List<Gym> gyms = gymService.getGyms();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(gyms, OK);
    }

    @ApiOperation(value = "Finding gym from list", notes = "Retrieve a gym from the search engine")
    @ApiResponses({@ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "The gym was found"),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "The request is malformed or invalid"),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "404", description = "The resource URL was not found on the server"),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "An internal server error occurred"),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "403", description = "You are not authorized. Please authenticate and try again"),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "401", description = "You don't have permission to this resource")
    })
    @GetMapping("/find/{gymName}")
    public ResponseEntity<Gym> getGym(@PathVariable("gymName") String gymName) {
        Gym gym = gymService.findGymByGymName(gymName);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(gym, OK);
    }

}
```

and this is the repository for it:

```
package app.gym.v1.Repo;

import app.gym.v1.Model.Domain.Gym;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface GymRepo extends JpaRepository<Gym, Long> {

    Gym findByGymName(String gymName);
}
```

finally this is the service for it:

```
package app.gym.v1.Service;

import app.gym.v1.Model.Domain.Gym;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public interface GymService {

    List<Gym> getGyms();

    Gym findGymByGymName(String gymName);
}
```

as you see I add all the required annotations but the same bug appear to me and keep giving me the same answer in the debugger:

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in app.gym.v1.Resource.API.GymControl required a bean of type 'app.gym.v1.Service.GymService' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'app.gym.v1.Service.GymService' in your configuration.

Process finished with exit code 0

*** I searched a lot about it and try every single answer here in StackOverFlow and every single answer in GitHub and reply a lot of books but everything like stop.

Comment: So far you defined `GymService` as an interface. You don't have any implementation of that - thus: there is no bean. You need to change it into a class, then it'll start working.

Comment: [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351780/where-should-service-annotation-be-kept-interface-or-implementation

Comment: @MirekPluta It's not working

Comment: @bhaskarkh I saw it and understand it

Answer (score 2):

[Where should @Service annotation be kept? Interface or Implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351780/where-should-service-annotation-be-kept-interface-or-implementation) you must check this .Basically you need to implement **GymService** interface  and then only it will work try like this.

```
@Service
public class GymServiceImpl  implements GymService{
    
    @Autowired
    GymRepo gymRepo

    @Override
    public List<Gym> getGyms() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return gymRepo.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Gym findGymByGymName(String gymName) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return gymRepo.findByGymName(gymName);
    }

}
```

Comment: It works but I can't put a like for the answer I don't have enough points to do that

Comment: You are able to accept the answer as correct. Please consider doing it ;) Thanks!