# Spring Data Rest - How to change the JSON serialization of a Collection of Abstract Classes

Tags: java, spring-data-rest

I use Spring Boot v1.2.5 and have the following single table inheritance entities:

```
@Entity    
@table(name="view_items")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="type")
public abstract class ViewItem {
   private int position;     
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value="table")
public class Table extends ViewItem {}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value="chart")
public class Chart extends ViewItem {}

public interface ViewItemRepository 
    extends JpaRepository<ViewItem, Integer>{}
```

And the following association:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="views")
public class View {

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="view_id")
    @OrderBy("position")
    private List<ViewItem> viewItems = new ArrayList<ViewItem>();

    ...
}
```

Calling `GET /views/{id}/viewItems` return the collection ordered by subclasse type (some parts have been removed for readability) :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: application/hal+json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Date: Wed, 23 Sep 2015 07:41:13 GMT

{
  "_embedded" : {        
    "tables" : [ {
      "position": 4,          
        ...
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/viewItems/3"
        }
      }
    } ],
    "charts" : [ {
      "position": 2,
        ...
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/viewItems/2"
        }
      }
    } ]
  }
```

Is there a simple way to change the JSON serialisation having `view_items` sorted by position like this ? :

```
{
  "_embedded" : {        
    "2": {
      "type": "chart",
        ...
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/viewItems/2"
        }
    },
    "4": {
      type: "table",
       ...
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/viewItems/3"
        }
  }
```

Comment: `@OrderBy("position asc")` ?

Comment: No luck. The problem is Spring Data Rest serialize into subcollections indexed by type. Maybe subcollections are ordered but it is not the wanted behaviour .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i found the answer.

Replacing the `ViewItems` collection mapping type of the `View` entity from `List` to `Map` and adding a read only `type` field on the `ViewItem` entity does the trick:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="views")
public class View {

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="view_id")
    @MapKey("position")
    private Map<Integer,ViewItem> viewItems = new HashMap<Integer,ViewItem>();
    ...
}

@Entity    
@table(name="view_items")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="type")
public abstract class ViewItem {

   @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
   public String type;

   ...  
}
```

**EDIT**

Months after, and thanks to @aux (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33403214/5276344)) here is the solution. A RelProvider class must be implemented, as explained [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/reference/html/#spis.rel-provider).