# Spring Data Rest Repository with abstract class / inheritance

Tags: spring, inheritance, spring-data, spring-data-rest, spring-data-keyvalue

I can't get Spring Data Rest with class inheritance working.

I'd like to have a single JSON Endpoint which handles all my concrete classes.

### Repo:

```
public interface AbstractFooRepo extends KeyValueRepository<AbstractFoo, String> {}
```

### Abstract class:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = MyFoo.class, name = "MY_FOO")
})
public abstract class AbstractFoo {
  @Id public String id;
  public String type;
}
```

### Concrete class:

```
public class MyFoo extends AbstractFoo { }
```

Now when calling `POST /abstractFoos` with `{"type":"MY_FOO"}`, it tells me: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: PersistentEntity must not be null!`.

This seems to happen, because Spring doesn't know about `MyFoo`.

Is there some way to tell Spring Data REST about `MyFoo` without creating a Repository and a REST Endpoint for it?

(I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.1 and Spring Data REST 2.6.0)

### EDIT:

Application.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableMapRepositories
public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25241995/1201725?

Comment: Please show your complete classes.

Comment: These are my complete classes. Only class left is my default Application class. I'll append it, but it's kinda useless.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm using Spring Boot `1.5.1` and Spring Data Release `Ingalls`.

`KeyValueRepository` doesn't work with inheritance. It uses the class name of every saved object to find the corresponding key-value-store. E.g. `save(new Foo())` will place the saved object within the `Foo` collection. And `abstractFoosRepo.findAll()` will look within the `AbstractFoo` collection and won't find any `Foo` object.

**Here's the working code using MongoRepository:**

### Application.java

Default Spring Boot Application Starter.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

### AbstractFoo.java

- I've tested `include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY` and `include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY`. Both seem to work fine!
- It's even possible to register the Jackson SubTypes with a custom JacksonModule.
- **IMPORTANT:** `@RestResource(path="abstractFoos")` is highly recommended. Else the `_links.self` links will point to `/foos` and `/bars` instead of `/abstractFoos`.

---

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Foo.class, name = "MY_FOO"),
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Bar.class, name = "MY_Bar")
})
@Document(collection="foo_collection")
@RestResource(path="abstractFoos")
public abstract class AbstractFoo {
  @Id public String id;
  public abstract String getType();
}
```

### AbstractFooRepo.java

Nothing special here

```
public interface AbstractFooRepo extends MongoRepository<AbstractFoo, String> { }
```

### Foo.java & Bar.java

```
@Persistent
public class Foo extends AbstractFoo {
  @Override
  public String getType() {
    return "MY_FOO";
  }
}

@Persistent
public class Bar extends AbstractFoo {
  @Override
  public String getType() {
    return "MY_BAR";
  }
}
```

### FooRelProvider.java

- Without this part, the output of the objects would be separated in two arrays under `_embedded.foos` and `_embedded.bars`.
- The `supports` method ensures that for all classes which extend `AbstractFoo`, the objects will be placed within `_embedded.abstractFoos`.

---

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class FooRelProvider extends EvoInflectorRelProvider {
  @Override
  public String getCollectionResourceRelFor(final Class<?> type) {
    return super.getCollectionResourceRelFor(AbstractFoo.class);
  }

  @Override
  public String getItemResourceRelFor(final Class<?> type) {
    return super.getItemResourceRelFor(AbstractFoo.class);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean supports(final Class<?> delimiter) {
    return AbstractFoo.class.isAssignableFrom(delimiter);
  }
}
```

---

## EDIT

- Added `@Persistent` to `Foo.java` and `Bar.java`. (Adding it to `AbstractFoo.java` doesn't work). Without this annotation I got NullPointerExceptions when trying to use JSR 303 Validation Annotations within inherited classes.

Example code to reproduce the error:

```
public class A {
  @Id public String id;
  @Valid public B b;

  // @JsonTypeInfo + @JsonSubTypes
  public static abstract class B {
    @NotNull public String s;
  }

  // @Persistent <- Needed!
  public static class B1 extends B { }
}
```

Comment: Heads up if using this for moving data in and out of mongodb with spring, you will need this as well: https://gist.github.com/letalvoj/978e6c975398693fc6843c5fe648416d

Comment: @Benjamin I saw ur JIRA issue about inheritance in SDR and there you mentioned you were able to use projection with inheritance hierarchy. I would be grateful if you could update it here as to how you got the projections to work

Answer (score 4):

Please see the discussion in this resolved [jira task](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-872)  for details of what is currently supported in spring-data-rest regarding `JsonTypeInfo`. And this [jira task](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-900) on what is still missing.

To summarize - only `@JsonTypeInfo` with `include=JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY` is working for serialization and deserialization currently.

Also, you need spring-data-rest 2.5.3 (Hopper SR3) or later to get this limited support.

Please see my sample application - https://github.com/mduesterhoeft/spring-data-rest-entity-inheritance/tree/fixed-hopper-sr3-snapshot

With `include=JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY` the type information is extracted from a regular property. An example helps getting the point of this way of adding type information:

The abstract class:

```
@Entity @Inheritance(strategy= SINGLE_TABLE)
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include=JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY,
        property="type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @Type(name="DECIMAL", value=DecimalValue.class),
        @Type(name="STRING", value=StringValue.class)})
public abstract class Value {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Getter
    private Long id;

    public abstract String getType();
}
```

And the subclass:

```
@Entity @DiscriminatorValue("D")
@Getter @Setter
public class DecimalValue extends Value {

    @Column(name = "DECIMAL_VALUE")
    private BigDecimal value;

    public String getType() {
        return "DECIMAL";
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I'm using spring-data-rest 2.6.0. And use `KeyValueRepository` (no JPA). My `AbstractFoo` class has now `include=JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY` and an abstract method `public abstract String getType()`. When posting data to `/abstractFoos` I still get `PersistentEntity must not be null!`. (Also tried Hopper SR7 with Spring Boot 1.4.4)

Comment: Do you have the full source code on github? Would like to have a closer look. Otherwise, it is hard to guess what's going wrong.

Comment: I just switched from `KeyValueRepository` to `MongoRepository` and now it's kinda working! Seems like `KeyValueRepository` can't handle inheritance. **Still some issue:** When executing `GET /abstractFoos` my Objects are located under `_embedded.foos` and `_embedded.bars`. Why aren't they just a single collection? Now I can't sort them. (Can be fixed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29021221/how-to-reference-an-entity-with-inheritance-in-spring-data-rest-when-posting-new/33403214#33403214 )

Comment: I'll post an answer that behaves correctly for `MongoRepository`. I came across lot's of pitfalls... Thanks for your help. You'll get the reward :)

Comment: The simple class name can also be used as discrminator "as existing property":

public String getType2() { return getClass().getSimpleName().toUpperCase();}