# Spring Data REST. Subclass handling

Tags: spring-data-rest, jackson-databind

I try to POST the object

```
    {
        "id": "SOME_ID",
        "foo": "http://localhost:8080/api/subclass-of-foo/OBJECT_ID"
    }
```

The **`Foo`** Class is abstract. Information about concrete class is in the link **`subclass-of-foo`**. But I get always
"**Cannot construct instance of `Foo` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information**".

I can't use **`@JsonDeserialize(as = Subclass.class)`** on **`Foo`**, because there are multiple sub-classes of **`Foo`**.

Where and how can I provide this information to fix the problem?

```java
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type", discriminatorType = STRING)
class abstract Foo {
  private id;
}

class Bar1 extends Foo {

}

class Bar2 extends Foo {

}

class Bar3 extends Foo {

}

@Entity
class X {
   private String id;

   @OneToOne
   private Foo foo;

}
```

And json payload to POST an X object:

```
    {
        "id": "X_ID",
        "foo": "http://localhost:8080/api/bar1/Bar1_ID"
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide a brief code example?

Comment: @SebastianUllrich done. Is it enough? Or you need more details?

Comment: My first guess is that `Foo` needs to be an @MappedSuperclass. Check here https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-inheritance

Comment: @SebastianUllrich I added an annotation to Foo to see the inheritance strategy I use.

Comment: This topic could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42121506/spring-data-rest-repository-with-abstract-class-inheritance