# Where to place @PreAuthorize, on interface or implementation

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I found that generally Spring annotations are recommended to be placed on implementation for example [@Transactional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120143/where-should-i-put-transactional-annotation-at-an-interface-definition-or-at-a/3120323), but where to place @PreAuthorized?

Comment: Generally speaking, you want to ask yourself "what this annotation a part of?". If it's a part of contract you want to expose to consumers of your beans/API, then put it in interface. If your consumers do not need to know about this in general, then its place is among implementation details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In official Spring Docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/authorization.html#el-pre-post-annotations they add these to the interface methods.

But I think you can add them also on the implementation.

Comment: unable to open the link