# @Transactional questions and how to use with @Service

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, service, transactions

My service makes use of a generic DAO (which explicitly uses Hibernate session factory). I have spent some time before I discovered this error

`org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here`

I annotated my service and all works perfectly. Now I want to use context path scanning, and remove this line from my configuration:

```
<bean id="societaService" class="it.trew.prove.services.SocietaService" />
```

So.... here's my final version:

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class SocietaService {

    private Dao societaDao;

    @Autowired
    public void setSocietaDao(Dao societaDao) {
        this.societaDao = societaDao;
    }

    public void salvaSocieta(Societa s) {
        societaDao.save(s);
    }

    public List<Societa> listAll() {
        return societaDao.getAll(Societa.class);
    }

    public void deleteById(Long id) {
        societaDao.delete(getSocieta(id));
    }

    public Societa getSocieta(String id) {
        return getSocieta(Long.parseLong(id));
    }

    public Societa getSocieta(Long id) {
        return societaDao.get(Societa.class, id);
    }
}
```

**Adding @Service annotation makes my app give the awful hibernate error above. Why?
Removing @Service and configuring the service bean via xml = it works. WHY??**

In addition:

- does transactional annotating my service class makes all its methods to be executing in a transaction?

**EDIT**

Here's my context xml:

```
<context:annotation-config />   
<context:component-scan base-package="it.trew.prove" /> 

<!--  Hibernate -->

<bean id="myDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.AppEngineDriver" />
<property name="url" value="jdbc:google:rdbms://xxx:xxx/xxx" />
</bean>


<bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>it.trew.prove.model.beans.Scadenza</value>
            <value>it.trew.prove.model.beans.Fornitore</value>
            <value>it.trew.prove.model.beans.Societa</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            <!-- <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files">/setup.sql</prop> -->
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Comment: show more of your xml configuration

Comment: I know that this is not a case here, but you cannot set `readOnly=true` if you have operations like delete or save. You should place a `@Transactional` with appropriate setting for each method.

Comment: [Spring - @Transactional - What happens in background?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099025/spring-transactional-what-happens-in-background) @ SO might help

Comment: Where in your application (what operation) is causing the exception and what does your `Dao` look like?

Comment: @pap it seems like if when I add Service annotation.... Transactional annotation stops working.

Comment: Sounds a bit like this ancient issue: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-3817

Answer (score 3):

Did you enabled annotations ?

```
<context:annotation-config />
```

and

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.example"/>
```

this will enable annotations like @Service, @Component and @Repository

Comment: I did not have the first line you wrote. However, the result does not change.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to tell spring to enable Transactional annotation with something like that:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

Second, if you use @Transactional at class level, any call to a method of your Service will be transactional. Whether it starts a transaction or not depends on the "propagation" attribute. The default is start one if none started in this session (Propagation.REQUIRED). If you use @Transactional only at class level, all of your methods will inherit its attributes, i.e., if you set "readOnly = true", all of yours methods will be read only, thus, updates/saves/delete won't work. I would recommend you to read more the [Spring Transaction Management Doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M2/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html)

Comment: I already had that line, as you can see in the edit. Thanks for the info however. I will read