# JPA/Hibernate with Spring Transactions not commiting

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-transactions

I recently added the JpaTransactionManager to my Config and tried using Spring transactions. It seems to work correctly, except for one test which I have added below.

Why am I not getting my expected `IllegalStateException`? I expect this to fail, because `CascadeType` is set to `NONE` on the `parentCategory` field.
If I add `em.flush();` inside my repository class, I do get the expected exception.

As I understand it, adding `@Transaction` in my tests only adds the begin, commit and rollback transaction methods. So it should fail at the commit method, but it doesnt.

According to the [Hibernate User Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations-transactions) the `hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion` is false by default. Is this the reason why I don't get my expected exception?

There is a [similair post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32033195/5473627) where a user states that the commit will cause a flush. This is also the reason why I decided to ask this question.

This is my entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
public class Category {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "category_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "category", nullable = false, unique = true)
  private String categoryName;

  @ManyToOne // Default is CascadeType.NONE
  @JoinColumn(name = "parent_category_id", referencedColumnName = "category_id")
  private Category parentCategory;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parentCategory")
  private List<Category> childCategories = new ArrayList<>();

  public Category(String categoryName, Category parentCategory) {
    this.categoryName = categoryName;
    this.parentCategory = parentCategory;
  }

  // default constructor, getters and setters ...
}
```

This is my repository

```
@Repository
public class CategoryDaoImpl {

  @PersistenceContext protected EntityManager em;

  @Override
  public E persist(E entity) {
    em.persist(entity);
    // em.flush(); // Why doesnt Spring transactions automatically add the em.flush()  inside the transaction?
    return entity;
  }

}
```

This is my test

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = DbConfig.class)
@Transactional
public class CategoryDaoTest {

  @Autowired private CategoryDao categoryDao;

  @Test(expected = IllegalStateException.class)
  public void createTwoCategoriesPersistChildAndGetIllegalStateException() {
    Category childCategory = new Category("firstChild", new Category("rootCategory", null));

    categoryDao.persist(childCategory);
  }

}
```

This is my config

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "nl.yoshuan.pricecomparer")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class TestConfig {

  @Bean
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
    return builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL).build();
  }

  @Bean
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    factory.setPackagesToScan("nl.yoshuan.pricecomparer.entities");
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource());

    Map<String, Object> jpaProperties = new HashMap<>();
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect");
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", true);
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.format_sql", true);
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.use_sql_comments", true);
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
    factory.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaProperties);

    return factory;
  }

  @Bean
  public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
  txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
    return txManager;
  }

}
```

This is my console output

```
2017-05-29 15:43:14 INFO  TransactionContext:101 - Began transaction (1) for test context [DefaultTestContext@971e903 testClass = CategoryDaoUTest, testInstance = nl.yoshuan.pricecomparer.dao.CategoryDaoUTest@2b2f5fcf, testMethod = addTwoCategoriesPersistChildAndGetIllegalStateException@CategoryDaoUTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@108531c2 testClass = CategoryDaoUTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class nl.yoshuan.pricecomparer.config.TestConfig}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextCustomizers = set[[empty]], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]]; transaction manager [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager@7661b5a]; rollback [true]
Hibernate: 
    /* insert nl.yoshuan.pricecomparer.entities.Category
        */ insert 
        into
            category
            (category_id, category, parent_category_id) 
        values
            (default, ?, ?)
2017-05-29 15:43:14 INFO  TransactionContext:136 - Rolled back transaction for test context [DefaultTestContext@971e903 testClass = CategoryDaoUTest, testInstance = nl.yoshuan.pricecomparer.dao.CategoryDaoUTest@2b2f5fcf, testMethod = addTwoCategoriesPersistChildAndGetIllegalStateException@CategoryDaoUTest, testException = java.lang.AssertionError: Expected exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException, mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@108531c2 testClass = CategoryDaoUTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class nl.yoshuan.pricecomparer.config.TestConfig}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextCustomizers = set[[empty]], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]].
2017-05-29 15:43:14 INFO  GenericApplicationContext:987 - Closing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@49206065: startup date [Mon May 29 15:43:14 CEST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-05-29 15:43:14 INFO  LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean:548 - Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-05-29 15:43:14 INFO  SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl:524 - HHH000477: Starting delayed drop of schema as part of SessionFactory shut-down'
Hibernate: 

    alter table category 
       drop constraint FKs2ride9gvilxy2tcuv7witnxc
Hibernate: 

    drop table category if exists
2017-05-29 15:43:14 INFO  EmbeddedDatabaseFactory:217 - Shutting down embedded database: url='jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb'

java.lang.AssertionError: Expected exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException

    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.ExpectException.evaluate(ExpectException.java:32)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Comment: Updated console output.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add `@TransactionConfiguration` to your unit test. TransactionConfiguration defines class-level metadata for configuring transactional tests.

Comment: `@TransactionConfiguration`  is deprecated and is not what I'm looking for. Neither is `@Rollback`. `@Commit` does work, but the exception is now occuring after my method. I get `java.lang.AssertionError: Expected exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException` and after that, I get my InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException --> TransientPropertyValueException --> IllegalStateException stacktrace