# Hibernate + Spring openSession in Transaction

Tags: java, hibernate

I have this code and I have a question :

```
@Service
class SimpleServiceImpl implements SimpleService{

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

@Transactional
public void doSmth(){
   // here I want to have a new session
   Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class).getSessionFactory().openSession();

   // do smth in new session
   session.close();
}
```

What about a transaction ??? Actually as I understand if I open session I have to manage this session explicitly and I have to close it. But what's going on with transaction? Should I begin a new transaction and manage it by myself or my action s continue in the same transaction which method doSmth began?

Answer (score 0):

You have annotated with @Transactional that's why Spring will handle transaction using AOP concept.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Transactional annotation your method will be done within one transaction.

For more information you could also check this: [spring transactional what happens in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099025/spring-transactional-what-happens-in-background).