# How spring @Transactional works JPA/hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-transactions

I am using JPA with spring transactions. I have observed  same session is alive  till athread exits method1. I believe its happening becoz of
`@Transactional` As per my understanding magic must be happening under the hood becoz of this

As soon as thread enters method1 , if any operation retrieves
entityManager(parallel to session in hibernate) . spring proxy binds that entityManager/session(which internally binds to database connection object)
with that thread so that down the line if any other operations asks for entityManager/session, spring will provide same entityManager/session.
Is that correct?

```
@Transactional
method1(){}
```

Comment: check this out ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099025/spring-transactional-what-happens-in-background

Comment: If you check your Spring/Hibernate config you should see some beans/config concerning a transaction manager.

Comment: @lalit that link mainly focus on how proxy does that. But here I am curious to know does spring binds the session with thread so that down the line if any other operations asks for entityManager/session under that thread, same entityManager/sessionis returned ?

Comment: @Tobb yes I can see those configurations

Comment: Then, Spring adds an `aspect` around any public method annotated with `@Transactional`, which will run the necessary code to start a transaction. Any JPA operation run after this will be part of an atomic operation, and thus also part of the same session.

Comment: @Tobb  so aspect will bind session with thread internally right ?

Comment: An aspect is just a general mechanism, but in this case it will.