# spring mvc interceptor request scope

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm developing a web app with Spring 4.1.7 and Hibernate 4.3.10.
I needed to create an Interceptor for manage transactions like this:

```
public class ControllerInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter
{

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

private Session session;

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
                         HttpServletResponse response,
                         Object handler) throws Exception
{
    super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
    ControllerInterceptor ci = this;
    session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    //Transaction management....
    return true;
}

@Override
public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request,
                            HttpServletResponse response,
                            Object handler,
                            Exception ex) throws Exception
{
    //Transaction commit/rollback
    if (null != session && session.isOpen())
    {
        try
        {
            session.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
}
```

In applicationContext.xml I defined the interceptor in this way:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="com.interceptor.ControllerInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptors>
```

My ControllerInterceptor is singleton but I need it in request scope.
I tried to define the interceptor in this way:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="com.interceptor.ControllerInterceptor" scope="request" />
</mvc:interceptors>
```

but I had this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
```

Any suggestion?Thanks

Comment: why do you need `request` scope for interceptor ?

Comment: Because I need to put some global variables into the interceptor to write and read them in preHandle and postHandle method

Comment: global variables as in ? share some examples..

Comment: It is not an answer to your question - but why do you want to start transaction at before controller method. It is antipattern - Open Session in View. You should limit your to transaction to least actions as possible.

Comment: Did you try to use what the error stated : `In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.`  ?

Comment: Sure, but it didn't help

Answer (score -1):

MVC interceptors need not have request scope as they are executed for *current request* only.

To quote from java docs of [HandlerInterceptor.preHandle](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html#preHandle-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse-java.lang.Object-) -

> Intercept the execution of a handler. *Called after HandlerMapping determined an appropriate handler object, but before HandlerAdapter invokes the handler*.
>   DispatcherServlet processes a handler in an execution chain, consisting of any number of interceptors, with the handler itself at the end. With this method, each interceptor can decide to abort the execution chain, typically sending a HTTP error or writing a custom response.
>
> Parameters:
>   
> request - **current** HTTP request
>   
> response - **current** HTTP response
>   
> handler - chosen handler to execute, for type and/or instance evaluation

Moreover as pointed correctly by Olesksii you need to avoid the anti-pattern of session / transaction management here.

Instead have a look at [@Transactional](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html). Suggested reads -> [this](https://dzone.com/articles/how-does-spring-transactional) , [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099025/spring-transactional-what-happens-in-background) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099025/spring-transactional-what-happens-in-background)

Comment: Why is it anti-pattern? I just need to manage an unique transaction per request. Can you suggest me a different solution please?

Comment: I read that @Transactional annotation is not suggested for Controller but only for service...

Comment: correct - because transaction should be kept as concise as possible.