# Annotating service methods as @Transactional - Managing connections

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, transactional

Do I need to annotate my Service methods as @Transactional to make sure that the connections opened by the Repository layer  is closed? What if I don't annotate as @Transactional? Will this lead to open connections\inactive sessions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring - @Transactional - What happens in background?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099025/spring-transactional-what-happens-in-background)

Comment: No. You need to annotate them as Transactional to make sure that everything done inside the method happens in a single, atomic, consistent, isolated, durable, transaction.

Comment: Connection handling is done within the connection pool, not in the transaction.