# spring @Transactional propagation in a() call b() and c()

Tags: java, spring

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public void a(){
    a();
    b();
}
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void b(){
    //do something
}
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void c(){
    //do something
}
```

the method b() and the method c() use same transaction? thanks.

Comment: I recommend reading this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099025/spring-transactional-what-happens-in-background to get a grasp on how `@Transactional` works and what happens in this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code should be corrected to prevent from recursive call as follows:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public void a(){
    c();
    b();
}
```

In this case c() and b() will not be executed in a transaction, @Transactional annotation is only valid if a method is called from outside class, not within the same class.

Comment: Although I understand what you are saying, I think 'called from outside class' is incorrect. Manually creating an instance and calling `a()` on it meets this criteria, but it wont work for obvious reasons.