# SDN Migration to 4.2: How does @Transactional works?

Tags: java, spring, transactional, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I'm trying to upgrade versions of SDN (`4.2.0.M1`) and neo4j-ogm (`2.0.5`) to the latest snapshots `4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` and `2.1.0-SNAPSHOT`.

Following the migration guide and some advises from other SO questions, I've wrapped all methods that interact with neo4j **session** with `@Transactional`. It's working fine with most of the cases, but there still are some exceptions (`Transaction is not current for this thread`) that I cannot understand.

Let me give an example:

```
@Service
public class ContactServiceImpl implements ContactService {

    @Inject
    private Session session;

    //...

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void addContact(String userId, String contactId) {
        Contact contact = new Contact();
        // Fill contact data

        session.save(contact);
    }

    @Override
    public void addContacts(String userId, Set<User> newContacts) {
        for (User contact : CollectionUtils.emptyIfNull(newContacts)) {
            addContact(userId, contact.getId());
        }
    }   
}
```

Here I've only annotated with `@Transaction` the `addContact` method, because It's the only one that interacts direcly with SDN, at least this was my thought :)

However, If I call the `addContacts` method, which simply iterates a list and call the annotated `addContact` method, It fails with the exception mentioned before. If I also annotate this method, it simply works well, but I don't understand why. Maybe I'm missing some basics about spring `@Transactional` annotation behaviour, so sorry if it's a brainless question.

Can anyone clarify why I need to annotate both methods?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Transactional` is a bit more complicated than most people think. What looks like it should work actually doesn't and sometimes vice versa.

In your case you have hit an unfriendly Spring issue: not understanding how `@Transactional` AOP proxying works when calling transactional methods *from within the same class*.

[This snippet from the official documenation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-decl-explained) is a good starting point to get a rough idea about the basics of Spring's transaction proxying.

A quick search of StackOverflow brought me [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099025/spring-transactional-what-happens-in-background) which does a great job of explaining the phenomenon you are seeing.

***Note:*** As of version 4.2, SDN now fully implements the Spring Transaction Platform.

Comment: If you need more detail add a comment and I'll expand my answer.

Comment: Thanks @digx1! Ishould have searched a bit more before asking the question, but I took for granted that the problem could be related to the SDN migration, my fault :) Thanks for both links, now all make sense