# @Transactional annotation works even if the transaction.commit() is called

Tags: java, spring-transactions

I am using Spring 3.0 in my application, for rollback the database transaction I am using @transactional annotation. In addition to this I am committing the transaction by calling transaction.commit() method. If I receive any exception, the @transactional annotation rollbacks it perfectly even if I called the works transaction.commit() manually. Can someone please clarify this what is happening in back-end.

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099025/spring-transactional-what-happens-in-background

Comment: No Mehraj. My question is slightly different: is the @transactional annotation rollbacks the committed transaction

Comment: Possible you're committing a different transaction?  Your question sounds like you may have a design issue.  Having a clear transactional boundary is very important.  If you're manually committing a transaction and using spring's AOP transaction management, that means it's not a clear boundary which can lead to consistency problems.  I'd really encourage you to re visit the design.

Comment: Thank you Taylor.