# Is it possible to create an Aspect that provides @AfterReturnin operation on method that was originally annotated with @Transaction?

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop, spring-transactions

First lets consider that we have CustomerRegister service that simply do its job.

```
@Service
class CustomerRegister {
    private final CustomerRegister customerRegister;

    CustomerRegister(CustomerRegister customerRegister) {
        this.customerRegister = customerRegister;
    }

    @Transactional
    public void create(Customer customer) {
        customerRegister.persist(customer);
    }
}
```

Later it was decided that it could be good to have a business metric about that registry operation.
The common choice is to use **org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.CounterService**

Note that:

> Using `@Transactional`, Spring dynamically creates a proxy that
>   implements the same interface(s) as the class you're annotating

If we decide to invoke

```
counterService.increment(REGISTY_METRIC);
```

within scope of create method then counter will be increased even in transaction was rollback.

My idea is to create an **aspect** that wraps that **[transactional proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099025/spring-transactional-what-happens-in-background)** (which wrapping original CustomerRegister service). That `@Aspect`component could then provides method annotated with `@AfterReturning(pointcut =` that
increment metric counter.

Other words:

1. How to implement aspect over another aspect?
2. How to implement aspect over transactional proxy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement the aspect as it is done normally. Just ensure the custom aspects' [`@Order`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/Order.html) is set to low value (*i.e. highest precedence e.g. `1`*) so that it executes before any other aspect which is transaction aspect in this case.

Refer below image (*[reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#tx-decl-explained)*) to understand the request flow graphically. By setting the appropriate order on the `custom advisor(s)` it can be made run before / after transaction advise without any special consideration.

[image: Spring Transaction execution flow]

Additional recommended read [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-ordering) to understand how aspect ordering is handled in Spring.