# Spring managed transactions @Transactional annotation

Tags: spring, jpa, transactions, spring-transactions

Propagation setting is REQUIRED.

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
```

Transaction is read/write.

In which scenario those are used? Please give me explain with example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring transaction default is

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
```

So you do not need to specify the propagation property.

So, **What does it mean by `@Transactional` annotation for a spring component ?**

- Spring framework will start a new transaction and executes all the method and finally commit the transaction.
- But If no transaction is exists in the `application context` then spring container will start a new transaction.
- If more than one method configured as `Propagation.REQUIRED` then transactional behavior assigned in a nested way to each method in logically but they are all under the same physical transaction.

**So, What is the result ?**
The result is if any nested transaction fail, then the whole transaction will fail and rolled back (do not insert any value in db) instead of commit.

Example:

```
@Service
public class ServiceA{

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void foo(){
        fooB();
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void fooB(){
        //some operation
    }

}
```

**Explanation :**
In this example `foo()` method assigned a transactional behavior and inside `foo()` another method `fooB()` called which is also transactional.
Here the `fooB()` act as nested transaction in terms of `foo()`. If `fooB()` fails for any reason then `foo()` also failed to commit. Rather it roll back.

Comment: Maybe off topic, but i just wanted to point out, that the @Transactional annotation on fooB() has no effect if called from foo() since it bypasses the spring proxy which takes care of the transaction management. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1099284/4261642

Answer (score 0):

This annotation is just to help the Spring framework to manage your database transaction.

Lets say you have a service bean that writes to your database and you want to make sure that the writing is done within a transaction then you use

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
```

Here is a small example of a Spring service bean.

```
@Service
class MyService {

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void writeStuff() {

      // write something to your database
    }   
}
```

The `Transactional` annotation tells Spring that:

- This service method *requires* to be executed within a transaction.
- If an exception gets thrown while executing the service method, Spring will rollback the transaction and no data is written to the database.