# @Transactional annotation works with saveAndFlush?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, transactional

I have the following implementation.

```
@Transactional
public void saveAndGenerateResult(Data data) {
    saveDataInTableA(data.someAmountForA);
    saveDataInTableB(data.someAmountForB);
    callAnAggregatedFunction(data);
}

public void saveDataInTableA(DataA a) {
    tableARepository.saveAndFlush(a);
}

public void saveDataInTableA(DataB b) {
    tableBRepository.saveAndFlush(b);
}

public void callAnAggregatedFunction() {
    // Do something based on the data saved from the beginning in Table A and Table B
}
```

It is important to use `saveAndFlush` to have the data immediately available to the `callAnAggregatedFunction` function to get an aggregated result and save it to another table. That is why I am not using `save` function which does not flush the transactions into database immediately as far as I know.

However, I am using a `@Transactional` annotation over the function `saveAndGenerateResult`, as I want to rollback the database transactions that I have done in that function in case of any failure which is normally ensured by having a `@Transactional` annotation over a method.

What will be the scenario in this specific case? I am using `saveAndFlush` which flushes the data immediately into the database table and if the last function (i.e. `callAnAggregatedFunction`) fails to write the data into the table, will the previous write operations in table A and table B will be rollbacked?

Comment: Some explanation. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46789481/4423636

Comment: The answer there was helpful @AtaurRahmanMunna. Upvoted with thanks. :)

Comment: My pleasure. :)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> Will the previous write operations in table A and table B be rollbacked?

Yes, unless your `saveAndFlush()` methods have their own transactions (i.e. with `propagation = REQUIRES_NEW`).

If they're all part of the transaction you started in `saveAndGenerateResult()`, all modifications made to the database will be rolled back in case of failure.

For more information: [Spring - @Transactional - What happens in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099025/spring-transactional-what-happens-in-background)

[Spring @Transactional - isolation, propagation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490852/spring-transactional-isolation-propagation)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It would be a great help if you could share some documentation or link so that I could read more about it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The links were really helpful. :)