# How to update Auto generated time stamp in Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, auditing

I am making use of Auditing with Spring Data JPA to automatically update the created by time stamp. I have a requirement, where i have to migrate some data for which the created by date should be updated with the value am setting through the application. I have debugged the code, the values are setting properly. But while calling

`fooRepository.save(fooEntity)`

The created by is getting overridden by the auto generated time stamp.
Is it possible to override the value?

I am also having a @Transactional annotation in Service level. While debugging i can see the date is getting replaced on the Entity returned by the save repository method.

Comment: Are you using `@CreatedDate`  then I have a solution?

Comment: @Eklavya - Yes i am using createdDate for date creation. I guess its something to do with Transactional annotation. Since the entity is under transaction life cycle, it is getting stored only when the entire method is completed. Once the save call is done, the value of creation date is getting replaced with autogenerated date. Once the entire method is computed, when the actual save happens, it is saving the autogenerated value.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a better way but you can follow.
First, create the entity

```
fooRepository.saveAndFlush(fooEntity);
```

and then update the `createdAt` data then save the entity again.

```
fooEntity.setCreatedAt(yourTime);
fooRepository.saveAndFlush(fooEntity);
```

Comment: Like i mentioned in my question, since am using a @Transactional on top of the method. The entity is getting persisted only once the entire methods is completed. It is not getting persisted each time i make a save repository call.

Comment: @SachinBose Did you check ?, cause persist won't work when creating an entity I think

Comment: Can you try `saveAndFlush(fooEntity)` ? It should work see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49855138/transactional-annotation-works-with-saveandflush

Answer (score 0):

Create new `enity` without `@CreatedDate` and new `repository` for that new entity.

Only use that new `repository` when you need to edit `CreatedDate` or `LastModifiedDate`

This seems to be a bad solution but is the only solution I can think of now.

I am looking for better solution to this problem