# Spring @Transactional does not succeed or hangs up

Tags: java, spring

I need help with my project since I am not familiar with the spring @transactional annotation. The question is why my application hungs up using the @transactional method but will not hung up without it. Also how do I solve this so that the transaction will suceed.

The scenario is that my application is set-up like this:

1. Uses declarative transaction Management
2. One method has the @transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class) annotation and accesses the database multiple times.
3. The said method calls another method that returns a String and accesses the database multiple times.
4. Transaction does not suceed finishing causes a deadlock on my application. It does not return any exception.

The Code below is sample snippet

```
 @Autowired
 JdbcTemplate template;

 @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
  public final void upsertData(){
  insertTable1(); // insert query to insert in table 1
  addReferencingData(); // was just called to update table but returns                something which is not used;
  //Hangs up before getting to next statement
  somePreparedStatmentSQLmergeTable1(mergesql,template); // query to merge in table 1
}

public final String addReferencingData(){
   updateTableA(); // update query to update values in table A
   updateTableB(); // update query to update values in table B
   mergeTable1(); // merge query to update or insert in table 1

  return someString;
}

    public static void somePreparedStatmentSQLmergeTable1(sql,template){
      template.batchUpdate(sql, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {

        public void setValues(final PreparedStatement ps, final int i){
         // setting parameters to be used
         }
         public int getBatchSize(){
         // returns size of data's
         }
      }
    }
```

Also added the default Transaction manager on my application-context.xml file.Transaction already works based on logs. Only in this specific method it does not work.

Updated some information to be clearer.

Comment: What happens if you exclude `mergeTable1();` call?

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099025/spring-transactional-what-happens-in-background

Comment: And you expect us to guess everything you do in your `insertTable1()`, `somePreparedStatementSQL` methods? Add the implementation? Generally if your application stops that is due to the fact that you are messing around with things in a wrong way (like obtaining a connection yourself instead of using the `JdbcTemplate` properly).

Comment: Hi sorry, No that is not my intention, I have just used general terms because  I can't divulge too much information due to the nature of my job. but those methods are actually mapped queries that does as it is stated. A PreparedStatementSQL and some Merge, Update and Insert Queries.
But I do agree with you it is a fact that I may be using some things which they are not intended for.

Comment: @StanislavL, It still does not work, Thanks for suggesting

Comment: @AmolRaje Thanks for the information will read about it