# What is the use of @Transactional with JPA and Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I'm learning about how to create REST API with JPA and Hibernate and a MySQL database and I see this @Transactional annotation. Can someone explain what is the use of this annotation?

For example I have this simple DAO class:

```
@Repository
public class EmployeeDAOHibernateImpl implements EmployeeDAO {

    // define field for entitymanager
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    // set up constructor injection
    @Autowired
    public EmployeeDAOHibernateImpl(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Employee> findAll() {

        // get the current hibernate session
        Session currentSession = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);

        // create a query
        Query<Employee> theQuery = 
                currentSession.createQuery("from Employee", Employee.class);

        // execute query and get result list
        List<Employee> employees = theQuery.getResultList();

        // return the results
        return employees;
    }

}
```

You can see the @Transactional used for findAll() method, but if I delete this @Transactional I get the same output... then what is the use of this @Transactional?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring - @Transactional - What happens in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099025/spring-transactional-what-happens-in-background)

Comment: It's nothing to do with JPA ... FWIW. That is Spring

Answer (score 90):

`@Transactional` annotation is used when you want the certain method/class(=all methods inside) to be executed in a transaction.

Let's assume user `A` wants to transfer 100$ to user `B`. What happens is:

1. We decrease A's account by 100$
2. We add 100$ to B's account

Let's assume the exception is thrown after succeeding `1)` and before executing `2)`. Now we would have some kind of inconsistency because `A` lost 100$ while `B` got nothing.
Transactions means all or nothing. If there is an exception thrown somewhere in the method, changes are not persisted in the database. Something called `rollback` happens.

If you don't specify `@Transactional`, each DB call will be in a different transaction.

Comment: a nice answer but an one thing should be added - in case of example code `@Transactional` is unnecessary, maybe it's "superstitious programming" where someone always adds @Transactional even if it has no effect "just in case" :)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation it's simple and clear!

Answer (score 52):

Generally the `@Transactional` annotation is written at the service level.

It is used to **combine more than one writes** on a database **as a single atomic operation**.

When somebody call the method annotated with `@Transactional` **all or none of the writes** on the database **is executed**.

In the case of read operations it is not useful and so it is in case of a single atomic write. You are using it in a single read (select) so adding or removing the `@Transactional` annotation has no impact.

Comment: In read operations it is useful if using Java Streams to place the select results...

Comment: worth to add that `@Transactional` should be used when there are multiple updates to entity that is in `persistent` state (managed by entity manager) , so `save()` could be not explicitly put in the code but setters are called on entity

Comment: @viruskimera can you elaborate or provide some link?

Comment: This isn't true. This annotation is very important if you are dealing with lazy fetching type between java entities. 
Imagine you have Table A (ID, NAME, B_ID) and Table B (ID, DESCRIPTION) and you query all of the elements in Table A. And a later part of you code you try to get Table B's description information. In this case hibernate tries to fire an other select. But if you don't have @Transaction annotation over your service layer, it will fail with LazyInitializationException, because your original transactional is closed but hibernate expect one to be alive.