# Spring Data JpaRepository "JOIN FETCH" returns duplicates

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-data-jpa

I'm writing a simple Spring Data JPA application. I use MySQL database. There are two simple tables:

- Department
- Employee

Each employee works in some department (Employee.department_id).

```
@Entity
public class Department {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department")
    List<Employee> employees;
}

@Entity
public class Employee {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private Department department;
}

@Repository
public interface DepartmentRepository extends JpaRepository<Department, Long> {
    @Query("FROM Department dep JOIN FETCH dep.employees emp WHERE dep = emp.department")
    List<Department> getAll();
}
```

The method `getAll` returns a list with duplicated departments (each department is repeated as many times as there are employees in this department).

Question 1: Am I rigth that this is a feature related not to Spring Data JPA, but to to Hibernate?
Question 2: What is the best way to fix it? (I found at least two ways: 1) use `Set<Department> getAll();` 2) use `"SELECT DISTINCT dep"` in `@Query` annotation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FROM Department dep JOIN FETCH dep.employees emp` expression generates native query which returns plain result `Department-Employee`. Every `Department` will be returned `dep.employees.size()` times. This is a JPA-provider expected behavior (`Hibernate` in your case).

Using `distinct` to get rid of duplicates seems like a good option. `Set<Department>` as a query result makes it impossible to get the ordered result.

Comment: Thank you! But Spring is supposed to make things simpler, more convenient. Why does one need to bother about such low-level concepts when working with Spring, OOP?

Comment: This is intentional behavior. It allows you to use `emp` as alias for single employee in where clause. For instance, `where emp.name like "%John%"`.

Comment: Spring give you not only simplicity, but flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use `LEFT JOIN FETCH` as well as `DISTINCT`. Normal `JOIN FETCH` uses an inner join so Departments without any employees will not be returned by your query. LEFT JOIN FETCH uses an outer join instead.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure about using `@Query` here. If you mapped these 2 entities via annotations `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne` this join is redundant.
And second moment here, why is `@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` here? Maybe you should set lazy init in `@OneToMany` ?
[Check out this resource, I hope you'll find it helpfull](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)

Answer (score -1):

With my knowledge, the use case you have mentioned, you don't need to define your own method and instead use `repository.findAll` which is inherited from `PagingAndSortingRepository` which extends `CrudRepository`  and implemented by `SimpleJpaRepository`. See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html)

So just leave the repository interface blank as below,

```
@Repository
public interface DepartmentRepository extends JpaRepository<Department, Long> {

}
```

Then inject and use it wherever you need, e.g. lets say with DepartmentService

```
public interface DepartmentService {
    
    List<Link> getAll();    
}

@Component
public class DepartmentServiceImpl implements DepartmentService {

    private final DepartmentRepository  repository;    

    // dependency injection via constructor
    @Autowired
    public DepartmentServiceImpl(DepartmentRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Department> getAll() {  
        return repository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I'm aware your approach 1) requires @Transactional to access department.getEmployees() 2) leads to `n+1 select problem`

Comment: 1. Why @Transactional  required to fetch the data ? 2.`FetchType.LAZY` will take care of the `n+1` problem i believe. Don't know much and if you could elaborate about it may be. My point here to `findAll` you don't need to implement anything and leverage already implemented by JPA. Worth looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27799455/hibernate-creating-n1-queries-for-manytoone-jpa-annotated-property

Comment: You can read my previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63675153

Comment: I read it but I feel the problem and solutions are unnecessarily complex where as it should not be. I use Oracle and normally for read only purpose transactional is never required strictly. Please see explanation about @Transactional here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10394857/how-to-use-transactional-with-spring-data . And also this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54326306/what-is-the-use-of-transactional-with-jpa-and-hibernate

Comment: I can use departmentService.findAll() to get the list of depertments. But then when I call departmens.get(0).getEmployees() an exception is thrown. @Transactional fixes this.

Comment: May  I know what is the exception ? if you are talking about your previous question then i would suggest to remove the transnational completely and check.. What we do with `JOIN FETCH` can also be done with using `findAll` from repository. Let me know the exception i will check and comeback.