# Why in controllers or services, we can reach lazy loaded proxy object but not in a subclass of AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-transactions

I asked this question but it is closed and i haven't get my answer exactly;
[Spring @Transactional annotation is not working in the provider class which is a subclass of AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60075331/spring-transactional-annotation-is-not-working-in-the-provider-class-which-is-a)

And I read this answer;
[Spring - @Transactional - What happens in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099025/spring-transactional-what-happens-in-background)

They said something about internal method call and external method call. But this works in any controller or service. Why not in provider class which annotated as @Component? Why can't Spring or Hibernate open a session in provider class even with @Transactional annotation? Is this something about spring security? What is the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go through the reference [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#tx-decl-explained)

> The following images shows a Conceptual view of calling a method on a
>   transactional proxy:

[image]

Now with this information , a method annotated with `@Transactional` will start a transaction only when the call to the method comes in through the proxy object of the class that has this annotated method. This call is mentioned as the **external call** by the experts in your previous question.

In case of your example ,

The implementation of abstract method [AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser()](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/authentication/dao/AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java#L287) is called from [AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate()](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/0809c04aa2e861c12b1e9da47d334a1718dac106/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/authentication/dao/AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java#L126) , which is a self invocation. This is what the experts mentions as **internal call** . Also note that the method `authenticate()` is not `@Transactional`

Go through the documentation under the section [Using Transactional](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#transaction-declarative-annotations)

> In proxy mode (which is the default), only external method calls
>   coming in through the proxy are intercepted. This means that
>   self-invocation (in effect, a method within the target object calling
>   another method of the target object) does not lead to an actual
>   transaction at runtime even if the invoked method is marked with
>   @Transactional. Also, the proxy must be fully initialized to provide
>   the expected behavior, so you should not rely on this feature in your
>   initialization code (that is, @PostConstruct).

In your provider class which is annotated with `@Component` the call to the proxy reaches a method which is not annotated with `@Transactional` and does a self-invocation or internal call to the method annotated with `@Transactional` , which does not work as explained earlier

With the Controller or Service , the method annotated with `@Transactional` is getting called first (external call) , which initiates a transaction . The code flow within the context of that method is in a transaction and all the subsequent methods are participating in that transaction and you do not see the `- no Session` exception.

Hope this helps