# Sonar issue - transactions

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, sonarqube, spring-transactions

I'm struggling with sonar issue:

> squid:S2229 "Methods should not call same-class methods with incompatible "@Transactional" values"

I'm not sure how am I supposed to resolve this. Should I add `@Transactional` above clean method or something? Or even delete `@Transactional` annotation.

```
@Override
public void clean(BooleanSupplier isInterrupted) {
        // other code
        while (shouldContinue(isInterrupted) && partitionsIterator.hasNext()) {
            PartitionDeleteSql partition = partitionsIterator.next();
            execute(partition);
        }
    }

@Transactional
public void execute(PartitionDeleteSql sql) {
       // other code
       getJdbcTemplate().execute(sql....());
       getJdbcTemplate().execute(sql....());
       getJdbcTemplate().execute(sql....());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that Sonar points as is that the non-transactional method `clean` calls transactional `execute`. Therefore the `@Transactional` annotation on `execute` is ignored and the method will not get executed in the transactional mode.

**You have to annotate either `clean` method or the whole class with `@Transactional`.**

Also the class itself has to be registered as a Spring bean using for example `@Service` or `@Copmonent`, otherwise the proxy wrapper bean will not be created for such class.

Read more at: [Spring - @Transactional - What happens in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099025/spring-transactional-what-happens-in-background)