Repository method call in a coroutine launched using async(Dispatchers.Default) does not give the same value as in the main thread
To demonstrate my problem, I have the following simplified code:
FamilyService:
@Service
class FamilyService(
    private val familyRepository: FamilyRepository
    private val childService: ChildService
) {
    @Transactional(rollbackOn = [Exception::class])
    fun createFamily(familyLastName: String, childrenNames: List<String>): Family = runBlocking {
        val family = createFamilyEntity(familyLastName)


        println("family (in main): ${familyRepository.findByIdOrNull(family.id) ?: "none"}")

        val children = childrenNames.map { name ->
            async(Dispatchers.Default) {
                childService.createChild(family.id, name)
            }
        }.awaitAll()

        family
    }

    private fun createFamilyEntity(familyLastName: String): Family {
        val family = Family(id = UUID.randomUUID(), familyLastName = familyLastName)

        return familyRepository.save(family)
    }
}

ChildService:
@Service
class ChildService(
    private val childRepository: ChildRepository,
    private val familyRepository: FamilyRepository
) {
    fun createChild(familyId: UUID, name: String): Child {
        println("family (in child): ${familyRepository.findByIdOrNull(familyId) ?: "none"}")
        
        val child = Child(id = UUID.randomUUID(), familyId = familyId, name = name)

        return childRepository.save(child)
    }
}

When the FamilyController calls FamilyService.createFamily, it prints in the console something like:
family (in main): Family(id=...,familyLastName=...,...)
family (in child): none
family (in child): none
family (in child): none

And returns an error upon calling the childService.createChild that the foreign key constraint of the child table is violated because the row associated to the provided family id does not exist in the family table. But it exists in the println in createFamily, I do not know why it does not exist when it is called in a different coroutine.
To be specific, the error looks like this (but with different context instead of family and child entity):
2024-04-24 14:41:29.743 ERROR 14984 --- [atcher-worker-3] [v:] [cid:] [huid:] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: insert or update on table "data_table_record" violates foreign key constraint "data_table_record_table_id_fkey"
  Detail: Key (table_id)=(176dfee6-7525-4741-a466-1acb85861317) is not present in table "data_table".


Transactions are not thread-safe (see "Transaction management" section in transactional apidoc). If you start a transaction from a thread, and then switch to another thread, it might not be aware of preceding actions in the transaction. Also, note that it might be far more optimized to do a batch insert from a single thread/context than trying to fire many independent inserts from many threads.

I doubt if you are on a full coroutine Spring stack as methods in your service class are not suspending functions. @Transactional are not supposed to be used with coroutines (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/64142241/8129835). As per Spring documentation you should use TransactionalOperator for transactions in coroutine.

This is not entirely correct, Spring does support @Transactional with suspend functions nowadays, but one should be indeed careful when mixing reactive and non-reactive APIs.
