# Spring Transactions and AOP proxies

Tags: java, spring-boot, transactions, aop

In many articles I read the following "Spring's declarative transaction is enabled with AOP proxies".

For a newbie like me, what does that mean exactly ?

On what kind of classes or beans can I use the @Transactional annotation ?

Do I have to add the maven dependency "spring-aop" in POM.xml ?

Is  @EnableTransactionManagement explicitely needed in order to make transaction work ?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099025/spring-transactional-what-happens-in-background answer your question?

Comment: Yes, this answers most of my questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring - @Transactional - What happens in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099025/spring-transactional-what-happens-in-background)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099025/spring-transactional-what-happens-in-background) which goes into a bit of detail on what `@Transactional` does and how it works.

Regarding your other questions.

> On what kind of classes or beans can I use the `@Transactional` annotation?

In theory on each class you want. Should you do this no. For instance, making your web layer, the transactional boundary is generally considered as being a bad idea, as it is your service layer that should be the transactional boundary.

> Do I have to add the maven dependency `spring-aop` in `pom.xml` ?

No. The `spring-tx` dependency already pulls this in itself. When using the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` (or another persistence related one) it will also be included automatically.

> Is `@EnableTransactionManagement` explicitly needed in order to make the transaction work?

It depends. Generally speaking in a Spring Boot application you won't need to add this, as Spring Boot will automatically enable this. If you don't use Spring Boot but just a regular Spring application you will need to add `@EnableTransactionManagement` or `<tx:annotation-driven>` when using XML to tell Spring to process the `@Transactional` annotations.

Comment: Can the @Transactional annotation be used on any class ?  For example, on the application I have to maintain, the Transactional annotation is used on a Controller class (class annotated with RestController).  And we often have the following exception :  " javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query "

Comment: In theory you can, should you no. Annotating your controller is generally a bad idea as the service layer is your transactional boundary, not your web layer.

Comment: So, it means that the TransactionRequiredException is not due to the fact that DB access is done in a Controller class, right ?