# Why do we need to use @Transactional if Hibernate already uses getTransaction() for each session?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, transactions

I am new to Hibernate. As far as I understood all modifying actions with Hibernate are done inside `entityManager.getTransaction().begin()` and `entityManager.getTransaction().commit()`, hence Hibernate under the hood always does everything within transaction boundaries (except for read-only operations). If so, why do we need to explicitly use `@Transactional` annotation?

**UPDATE**

So basically I can write something like

```
void foo() {
    try {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        ...
        em.persist(a1); // 1 operation
        ...
        em.persist(a2); // 2 operation
        ...
        em.commit();
    catch (Exception e) {
        em.rollback();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

which is equivalent to

```
@Transactional
void foo() {
    em.persist(a1);
    ...
    em.persist(a2);
}
```

or if I want to split all my actions into more than one method, I create one wrapper method, annotate it with `@Transactional` and then call other methods within this wrapper method

```
@Transactional
void call() {
    foo();
    bar();
}

void foo() {
    em.persist(a1);
}

void bar() {
    em.persist(a2);
}
```

And both `foo()` and `bar()` will be executed in terms of one transaction, is that correct?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099025/spring-transactional-what-happens-in-background might help.

Answer (score 1):

If you only ever make a single insert/update/delete per transaction, yes than using `@Transactional` is unnecessary. But if you want to make multiple insert/update/delete than `@Transactional` can be used to group all those to a single transaction.